# Java : File.toURI().toURL() on Windows file

Tags: java, url, uri, filepath, file-uri

The system I'm running on is Windows XP, with JRE 1.6.

I do this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println(new File("C:\\test a.xml").toURI().toURL());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

and I get this : `file:/C:/test%20a.xml`

How come the given URL doesn't have two slashes before the `C:` ? I expected `file://C:...`. Is it normal behaviour?

---

**EDIT :**

From Java source code : java.net.URLStreamHandler.toExternalForm(URL)

```
    result.append(":");
    if (u.getAuthority() != null && u.getAuthority().length() > 0) {
        result.append("//");
        result.append(u.getAuthority());
    }
```

It seems that the Authority part of a file URL is null or empty, and thus the double slash is skipped. So what is the authority part of a URL and is it really absent from the file protocol?

Comment: I really hope that you put spaces before `{`s...

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running on? Actually doesn't matter if you can parse it back with new URL(String).

Comment: @kd304 : well it matters if I'm parsing the result with something else than URL(String), which I do.

Comment: Amusingly, the javadoc for java.net.URL still refers to the original NCSA Mosaic help pages, which unsurprisingly, is a dead link. I think I might file a bug against that....

Comment: @subtenante: Why would you parse it yourself?

Comment: @kd304 : not myself, but some other library.

Comment: I think the `file://C:...` is a Windows 'relaxation': it should properly be `file:///C:...`. See http://superuser.com/questions/352133.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's an interesting question.

First things first: I get the same results on JRE6.  I even get that when I lop off the toURL() part.

[RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) does not actually require two slashes.  According to section 3:

> The URI syntax is dependent upon the
>   scheme.  In general, absolute URI are
>   written as follows:
>
> ```
> <scheme>:<scheme-specific-part>
> ```

Having said that, RFC2396 has been superseded by [RFC3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html), which states

> The generic URI syntax consists of a
>   hierarchical sequence of omponents
>   referred to as the scheme, authority,
>   path, query, and fragment.
>
> ```
>   URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
>   hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
>               / path-absolute
>               / path-rootless
>               / path-empty
> ```
>
> The scheme and path components are
>   required, though the path may be empty
>   (no characters).  When authority is
>   present, the path must either be empty
>   or begin with a slash ("/") character.
>   When authority is not present, the
>   path cannot begin with two slash
>   characters ("//").  These restrictions
>   result in five different ABNF rules
>   for a path (Section 3.3), only one of
>   which will match any given URI
>   reference.

So, there you go.  Since file URIs have no authority segment, they're forbidden from starting with //.

However, that RFC didn't come around until 2005, and Java references RFC2396, so I don't know why it's following this convention, as file URLs before the new RFC have always had two slashes.

Comment: Yes but : http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738 . Section 3.10 tells me files should have double slashes in URLs.

Comment: And the example at the end of section 1.1 of RFC3986 has this example : file:///etc/hosts.

Comment: I noticed that, too.  Sometimes I think they should just make the specs easier to read.

Comment: [Section 3.2.2 of RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) clarifies this by noting that the `authority` may be empty: "_If the URI scheme defines a default for host, then that default applies when the host subcomponent is undefined or when the registered name is empty (zero length).  For example, the "file" URI scheme is defined so that no authority, an empty host, and "localhost" all mean the end-user's machine, whereas the "http" scheme considers a missing authority or empty host invalid._"

Comment: Yeah the URL RFC1738 seems to contradict this as GhiOm says: see also  http://superuser.com/questions/352133. Note that *some libraries expect the triple-slash version*, such as the Subversion Java bindings JavaHL API, so you have to manually do `"file://" + myFile.toURI().getRawPath()`

Answer (score 2):

To answer why you can have both:

```
file:/path/file
file:///path/file
file://localhost/path/file
```

[RFC3986 (3.2.2. Host)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) states:

> "If the URI scheme defines a default for host, then that default applies when the host subcomponent is undefined or when the registered name is empty (zero length). For example, the "file" URI scheme is defined so that no authority, an empty host, and "localhost" all mean the end-user's machine, whereas the "http" scheme considers a missing authority or empty host invalid."

So the "file" scheme translates `file:///path/file` to have a context of the end-user's machine even though the authority is an empty host.

Answer (score 1):

As far as using it in a browser is concerned, it doesn't matter. I have typically seen `file:///...` but one, two or three '/' will all work. This makes me think (without looking at the java documentation) that it would be normal behavior.

Comment: I understand 3 slashes : // + /C: which is logical. The problem is that I am not using a browser.

Comment: 3 Slashes makes sense on a UNIX-type system; the third slash is the root directory. file:///etc/passwd is the /etc/passwd file.