# How does neo4j on Windows resolve file name paths in cypher load csv in interactive browser session?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I've looked at all the other questions on this subject, and all answers (even those approved) are either incomplete or wrong. So, I'm providing specific examples in hopes of getting a clear explanation.

I've tried the following settings in neo4j.conf, and all appear to process the same way:

```
dbms.directories.import=d:\\import\\
dbms.directories.import=d:/import/
dbms.directories.import=d:/import
```

with the following commands in the browser interactive session, the results are in the comment above each version of the command

```
// URI is not hierarchical
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row

// Invalid input '/', makes sense but violates "correct" syntax seen online
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM file:/d:Endpoint.csv AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM file://d:/import/Endpoint.csv AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM file:///d:/import/Endpoint.csv AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row

// works, but the drive letter used is completely ignored
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/d:Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row

// works
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row

// Cannot load from URL 'file://Endpoint.csv': file URL may not contain an authority section (i.e. it should be 'file:///')
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file://Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row

// URI is not hierarchical
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:d:/import/Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:d:\\import\\Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row

// Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/d:/import/import/Endpoint.csv
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///d:/import/Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///d:\\import\\Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
dbms.directories.import=d:/import

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row
```

It will look for the files relative to the configured import directory.

If you remove (comment out) the config option, you can provide absolute paths too.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///d:/import/Endpoint.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 4 RETURN row
```

Comment: I started with the config option commented out, and could have sworn I tried the syntax you specified first, and when that failed I started down this investigation path. However, it's working correctly now. d:/dev/foo/import was my original path (same user rights) and that wasn't working. However, the simplest solution is working correctly now. I must have done something wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All file URIs are resolved relative to the path provided in `dbms.directories.import`. So with your settings, `file:///Endpoint.csv` is the "most correct" way to load `D:\import\Endpoint.csv`.

The reason we limit LOAD CSV to relative paths *under* the specified path is to prevent arbitrary filesystem access from Cypher.

The reason `/` and `///` both work is because "file URLs don't have an authority segment", and so it can be ommitted. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131273/java-file-touri-tourl-on-windows-file).)

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned to Michael, my initial simple approach failed the first time which is what prompted me to set the import folder. I like it much better without it, and can't recall exactly why I was initially getting a load failure now. KISS is best.

Answer (score 0):

If your "Database location" is: C:\path1\Neo4jMyData\
 
 (set after starting  C:\programs_path\neo4j-ce.exe)

1.The directory C:\path1\Neo4jMyData\import\   **must to exist**

2.do this:   copy C:\path2......\people_LOCAL.csv   c:\path1\Neo4jMyData\import\

3.in Neo4J console Community Edition in the browser:

LOAD CSV FROM "file:///people_LOCAL.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Person {userId: toInt(row[0]), name:row[1]})

4.It's work for me (under Windows) 13-10-2016 10:55

---Here is "people_LOCAL.csv"  for your test.---

```
1,"John"
10,"Jane"
234,"Fred"
4893,"Mark"
234943,"Anne"
```